# JSONSerialization Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)

Tags: alamofire, swift3

Why does the following code give me the error:

> Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue).

The error is thrown on this line:

```
urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)
```

Full code:

```
let parameters:Parameters = ["resource":[
        [
            "appUserCode":uuidString,
            "productNFCode": self.nfCode!,
            "status":code,
            "applicationKey":appDelegate.api_key
        ]
        ]
    ]
    do {

        urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)
    } catch {
        // No-op
    }
```

Comment: If I am getting it right, your `"status"` key contains `code` value which is of type `Enum`, then this error will occur. Change code to `code.rawValue`.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If your problem is still not resolved by the answer given here. I believe one of your objects inside the `parameters` might not be an instance of `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary`, or `NSNull`. As given in the documentation for `JSONSerialization` class:

> An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following properties:
>
> 1. The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.
>      All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.
> 2. All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.
>      Numbers are not NaN or infinity.
> 3. Other rules may apply. Calling isValidJSONObject(_:) or attempting a conversion are the definitive ways to tell if a given object can be converted to JSON data.

So, please check if any of the objects in your `parameters` object doesn't satisfy the above constraints.

Comment: Every key value is fine in my case still I am getting this error @KrishnaCA

Comment: @Mansuu.... please check if one if your strings are optional as given below

Comment: how do I convert my codable class object into a valid JSON object?

Answer (score 56):

I had this problem and it was because one of my strings was Optional.  It was trying to serialize a value like:
"Optional(\"string value\")"

Instead of "string value"

Comment: Me too, just had to make my parameters String instead of String?.

Comment: What do u do when you have to have a null value in your JSON? According to [http://www.json.org/](http://www.json.org/), a JSON can hold null values.

Comment: Solved my problem too. I thought it was first NSNull() values with Swift 3 but it only came from an Optional string.

Comment: rudenudedude something like this works for me                                                                                              let params: [String: Any] =
            ["someValue": [
                "someNestedValueKey": min ?? NSNull(),
                ]
        ]

Answer (score 24):

Just in case anyone is still having problems and is using Enums, another cause may be if you are passing an Enum value and not it's rawValue.

Example:

```
enum Status: String {
  case open
  case closed
}
```

**instead of passing the enum**:

```
params = ["status": Status.open]
```

**pass**

```
params = ["status": Status.open.rawValue]
```

Comment: Had exactly this! Thanks :)

Answer (score 20):

You can call this method too and see if your parameter can be converted to a JSON object, this will return a Bool.

```
let checker = JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(parameters)
```

Answer (score 7):

In my case I accidentally added an object to the Parameters dictionary instead of a string

Answer (score 3):

If you're using **SwiftyJSON** to access a JSON object, it's important to use the **`dictionaryObject`** property of the JSON (instead of using `dictionaryValue`, `dictionary` or nothing at all), because you will get this error (or a variation of it) otherwise. For example:

```
guard let jsonDict = json.dictionaryObject else {
    return
}

let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDict, options: [])
```

Comment: You sir, are a legend. Please know that.

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when used a `Set` that is linked with Foundation `NSSet`.

```
let myArray = Array(mySet)
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem and error as you! FINALLY found the issue...

**My code**:

```
params = [
    "gender": request.gender.first ?? "",
    "age": 15
]
```

**Problem**: Even though `request.gender.first ?? ""` returns a string, its a type of `String.Element`, which ANY `JSONEncoder` or `JSONSerialization` cannot encode (and is not in the list of types it can handle, according to documentation).

**Solution**:

```
params = [
    "gender": request.gender.first?.description ?? "",
    "age": 15
]
```

*Typically, just make sure its a string or an appropriate number the Encoders can handle...*

Answer (score 0):

You should convert `NSObject` to `NSDictionary` at first

Try this to convert to `NSDictionary`.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

//Add this utility method in your class.
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithPropertiesOfObject:(id)obj {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    unsigned count;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([obj class], &count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(properties[i])];
        [dict setObject:[obj valueForKey:key] ? [obj valueForKey:key] : @"" forKey:key];
    }

    free(properties);

    return [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:dict];
}
```

Then call this:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic options:0 error:&err];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this *runtime* error because my dictionary was like this:

```
var dictionary: [AnyHashable: Any] = [:]
let elapsedTime = Date.timeIntervalSince(oldDate)
dictionary["elapsedTime"] = elapsedTime
```

**Can you tell me what the problem is?** <sub><sup>hover your mouse on the box below to see answer!</sup></sub>

> `elapsedTime`'s type is `Function` it's not `TimeInterval`. 
>
>  I needed to change `Date.` to `Date().` ie use the instance method rather than the static method. 
>
>  When you're dictionary values are `Any` then this sort of issue doesn't get found until a runtime error where it can't serialize the dictionary to a JSON string...