# Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue) when trying to put method with Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

I tried to make a put request to server with JSON type and it gives me error.
Here is error detail.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write
>   (_SwiftValue)'

Here is a code.

```
var attdList : JSON = [:]
...
var clientsAry = attdList["clients"]
...
let params = ["clients" : clientsAry, "submitted" : 1]
...
Alamofire.request(url + req_task, method: .put, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding(options: []), headers:headers).responseJSON { response in
...
```

I printed params variable and it displays like this.
Could anyone please help this?

```
▿ 1 element
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : "clients"
    ▿ value : [
  {
    "id" : null,
    "hours" : "0",
    "client" : {
      "id" : 2,
      "name" : "Anders Andersson"
    }
  },
  {
    "id" : null,
    "hours" : "1",
    "client" : {
      "id" : 4,
      "name" : "Gun Gunsson"
    }
  },
  {
    "id" : null,
    "hours" : "2",
    "client" : {
      "id" : 3,
      "name" : "Johan Johansson"
    }
  },
  {
    "id" : null,
    "hours" : "3",
    "client" : {
      "id" : 1,
      "name" : "Maria Martinsson"
    }
  }
]
      ▿ rawArray : 4 elements
        ▿ 0 : 3 elements
          ▿ 0 : 2 elements
            - key : "id"
            - value : <null>
          ▿ 1 : 2 elements
            - key : "hours"
            - value : "0"
          ▿ 2 : 2 elements
            - key : "client"
            ▿ value : 2 elements
              ▿ 0 : 2 elements
                - key : "id"
                - value : 2
              ▿ 1 : 2 elements
                - key : "name"
                - value : Anders Andersson
        ▿ 1 : 3 elements
          ▿ 0 : 2 elements
            - key : "id"
            - value : <null>
          ▿ 1 : 2 elements
            - key : "hours"
            - value : "1"
          ▿ 2 : 2 elements
            - key : "client"
            ▿ value : 2 elements
              ▿ 0 : 2 elements
                - key : "id"
                - value : 4
              ▿ 1 : 2 elements
                - key : "name"
                - value : Gun Gunsson
        ▿ 2 : 3 elements
          ▿ 0 : 2 elements
            - key : "id"
            - value : <null>
          ▿ 1 : 2 elements
            - key : "hours"
            - value : "2"
          ▿ 2 : 2 elements
            - key : "client"
            ▿ value : 2 elements
              ▿ 0 : 2 elements
                - key : "id"
                - value : 3
              ▿ 1 : 2 elements
                - key : "name"
                - value : Johan Johansson
        ▿ 3 : 3 elements
          ▿ 0 : 2 elements
            - key : "id"
            - value : <null>
          ▿ 1 : 2 elements
            - key : "hours"
            - value : "3"
          ▿ 2 : 2 elements
            - key : "client"
            ▿ value : 2 elements
              ▿ 0 : 2 elements
                - key : "id"
                - value : 1
              ▿ 1 : 2 elements
                - key : "name"
                - value : Maria Martinsson
      - rawDictionary : 0 elements
      - rawString : ""
      - rawNumber : 0
      - rawNull : <null>
      - rawBool : false
      - type : SwiftyJSON.Type.array
      - error : nil
```

Comment: Are you using `swiftyJSON` ?, and what's the type of `clientsAry ` ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using SwiftyJSON and clientsAry is a JSON type I think as shown on above result.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40437179/7629882, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40326859/7629882

Comment: Sorry but I already checked and I don't find answer yet

Comment: you should convert `clientsAry`'s type as JSON to `Array<Dictionary[String:String]>`

Comment: Could you please show me that code? I don't know how to do that. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186969/discussion-between-arash-and-zhengge-che).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message indicates that an illegal type is used (`Parameters`), JSON supports only `string`, `number`, `<null>` and `array` / `dictionary`.

You should cast your JSON data to String:

```
let jsonData =  try JSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(attdList, options: .prettyPrinted) // first of all convert json to the data
    let convertedString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) // the data will be converted to the string
```

then send your data to server:

```
let params = ["clients" : convertedString, "submitted" : 1]
...
Alamofire.request(url + req_task, method: .put, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding(options: []), headers:headers).responseJSON { response in
...
```

Comment: Please, suggest native Swift types like `JSONSerialization` instead of `NSJSONSerialization`. Also you can suggest that he can start using `Codable` instead of SwiftyJSON and then he can just easily encode the data using `JSONEncoder`